# Oracle: What is bad # for ‘Space Allocated/Used” and ‘ITL Waits’ in V$SEGMENT_STATS

Tags: performance, oracle

I ran a query against the V$SEGMENT_STATISTICS view today and got some possibly disturbing numbers. Can some one let me know if they are bad or if I just reading to much into them?

DB has been up since 01-JAN-2011 so they represent the stats since then. DB size is 3TB

```
OBJECT_NAME       OBJECT_TYPE   STATISTIC_NAME         VALUE
XXPK0EMIANCE      INDEX         space allocated        27,246,198,784
ITEMINTANCE       TABLE         space allocated        22,228,762,624
LITEMINSTANCE     TABLE         space used             19,497,901,889
XXPK0TEMINSTANCE  INDEX         space used             17,431,957,592
```

on the XXPK0EMIANCE index the inital extent is 64k

also these

```
OBJECT_NAME       OBJECT_TYPE   STATISTIC_NAME         VALUE
XXPK0MINSTANCE    INDEX         ITL waits               1,123
XXIEKILSTANCE     INDEX         ITL waits                 467
```

If these are bad do they impact performance? My understanding is that being wait states, things stop until they are resolved. Is that true.

Also these looked high, are they?

```
LATION_PK         INDEX        logical reads         242,212,503,104
XXAK1STSCORE      INDEX        logical reads         117,542,351,984
XXPK0TSTANCE      INDEX        logical reads         113,532,240,160
TCORE             TABLE        db block changes        1,913,902,176
SDENT             TABLE        physical reads             72,161,312
XXPK0PDUCT        INDEX        segment scans              35,268,027
ESTSORE           TABLE        buffer busy waits           2,604,947
XXPK0SUCORE       INDEX        buffer busy waits             119,007
XXPK0INSTANCE     INDEX        row lock waits                 63,810
XXPK0EMINSTANCE   INDEX        row lock waits                 58,129
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These figure are for the best part of 6 months. I don't think you can really draw anything meaningful from them.

I think you would be better spending your time looking at the reports from AWR (or statspack if you don't have the diagnostics and tuning license). Look at the performance over a 1 hour snapshot during your busy periods and see if anything stands out there.

From a performance perspective, if nobody is complaining, there is probably nothing wrong.

---

Yes. When an object needs more space it is an overhead. The question is, how often does it need more space and do the users notice an significant issue when this happens. As I suggested earlier. If the users do not perceive a problem, then there probably isn't a problem. I know that sounds a bit reactive, rather than proactive, but there is little point wasting time tuning something that is not causing a problem. :)

As for the stats. Yes. Oracle tracks them and yes, they are useful. My problem with it is you are looking at the stats over a 6 month period. I'm not sure this gives anything useful you can work with. For example, what if most of those figures were accumulated in the first month, then the database has done nothing in the subsequent 5 months, or vice versa. Using these figures doesn't allow you to draw any conclusions in itself.

Reports such as AWR and statspack use the same database statistics, but report a change over time. For example, the change in the stats over the last hour. If I look at a snapshot spanning my busy periods and see that the database is being hammered, I might want to take a look at what is using all the resources. If I check the AWR/statspack report for my busy period and the database is quiet, what is the point in trying to tune it. It's doing nothing.

So the stats are useful, but you have to understand how the context in which they are used affects their value.

Comment: Absolutely true.  Aggregated values high information from us. The longer the period of time covered, the less meaning attached to the aggregation.  Also, periodic snapshots are valuable, because they allow us to identify trends.

Comment: As far as i understand it, every time Oracle needs to add space to an index or table, processes that are writing to it need to wait until space is added.  Its a very fast process but it still takes some time and resources,  My concern is that it is happening so often on some objects that there must be some penalty for it.  Is that correct or is there no cost.  If so why is it monitored by Oracle and displayed in the statistics view?

Comment: @user722226: `space allocated` and `space used` are bytes used, not wait time.  There's probably not much you can do about those numbers unless you redesign your schema or use compression.

Comment: Don't think that is correct.  The values given are no where near the actual values for those tables and indices.  Also there are about 20 tables/indices listed in the view, yet we have 100s of tables and 1000s of indices many much bigger than those.  in addition there are indices on same tables as those listed that are not listed in that view, only select ones.  What I have noticed is that they tend to be on heavily used tables that have very small initial extents (64k) in this case.

Comment: @user722226: If you create a table the initial values for `space allocated` is identical to the bytes from user_segments.  The values must age out over time, but I'm not sure what the algorithm is, and why some objects would have values and others wouldn't.